# Deep link in Slack not changing the channel in the app

Tags: deep-linking, slack

I'm trying to make a deep link work in slack following the documentation  [here](https://api.slack.com/reference/deep-linking) using different combinations (open an app, open a DM to a user) but nothing seems to be working. I found the team ID in the URL of the web app (https://app.slack.com/client/T0CCWXXXXX), a Slack APP ID from my APP dashboard and my personal ID.

For example, for the APP I tried slack://app?team={T0CXXXXX}&id={A01BXXXXX}&tab=home

It does open Slack but it doesn't lead me to any channel I ask it to.

Anyone know what's going on here, please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the curly brackets. The correct syntax is:

slack://app?team=T0CXXXXX&id=A01BXXXXX&tab=home

Good luck